# Google docs queuing system using UML class diagrams

Tags: uml, class-diagram

How to represent a system like google docs queuing system using UML class diagrams? I haven't used much UML and trying to design a system like Google docs.

Comment: Either you provide some more info about how Google docs works and what you want to present whom. Or you make an attempt and present that for a discussion. This way it's off-topic from my POV.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Basically I have to design a queuing system and my user tell me that it should be the same like google docs. I will do some readup on what exactly google docs works, but any queing system sample would be good for reference if you can provide them please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a UML pro but I took a quick stab at it. There's probably some missing pieces here but I think it's a good start.  It would be great if someone who knows how to correctly model this can provide their diagram.

[image]

Comment: The diagram as such is almost ok. The aggregation does not make sense. Also: where is that requested queue? (I don't know G.queue at all)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Thomas.  What would make sense for the associations?  Also what are your thoughts on the multiplicity?  I didn't give much thought on those.

Comment: Since I don't know the system I can't tell whether there is a 1/1 relation User/Account (probably not true, though desired). But a 1/1 is an indication for not having a composite aggregation but rather a simple association.